# What properties would a rationally dimensional object have?

Tags: rational-numbers, dimension-theory-analysis

I've been looking at how many vertices, lines, areas, etc. that n-cubes possess. One interesting thing to fall out of these calculations is that they are continuous over the rational numbers. 
The number of vertices a cube in n dimensions possesses is defined as $2^d$, where d is the dimension number. My question is, outside of abstract math, what properties would non-integer dimensions possess?

For instance, what would a 1.5 dimensional circle look like? Would there be regular polytopes?

Comment: Google Fractal dimension

Comment: Normally when a two-dimensional object becomes twice as big it's area increases four times. But the area of a Sierpinski triangle increases three times. So it's Dimension is somewhere between one and two